# how to get a response from a post request

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

I have a post request. It is made and completed successfully, but I would like to know how I could use `console.log(res.valor)` in it, follows the data

```
consultarCorreio(){
  this.cartS.cart.valorTotalItems
  this.cartS.getCorreiosPrazoPreco(this.cartS.cart.pesoTotal, 80220060, this.formGeral.value.entrega_cep).subscribe((res: any) => {
    if (res.error) {
      this.modalS.createModal(MdAlertComponent, { title: 'Erro ao obter dados do período', message: 'Recarrega a página e tente novamente ou espere alguns minutos. Se o erro persistir, entre em contato com a nossa equipe.' });
      return;
    }
    console.log(res.data.valor)
    this.freteCorreio = res.data.valor
    console.log(this.freteCorreio)
  });
}
```

Returns this json (res)

```
{
"status": true,
"data": {
"cServico": {
  "Codigo": "04510",
  "Valor": "65,00",
  "PrazoEntrega": "6",
  "ValorSemAdicionais": "65,00",
  "ValorMaoPropria": "0,00",
  "ValorAvisoRecebimento": "0,00",
  "ValorValorDeclarado": "0,00",
  "EntregaDomiciliar": "S",
  "EntregaSabado": "N",
    "obsFim": {},
  "Erro": "0",
    "MsgErro": {}
   }
 }
}
```

How can I use `console.log(res.Valor)` to get the value of "Valor" (65.00)
I tried using `console.log(res.value)` but it returned `undefined`.

Comment: Please make your question **title** English as well. (Or post at [SO in Portuguese](http://pt.stackoverflow.com).)

Comment: sorry i edited the question now

Comment: @T.J.Crowdercan you vote again on my question?

Comment: I had already removed my close vote before asking you to fix the title (since I saw the text was in English). (I don't downvote things like that.)

Comment: I don't understand why they voted negative for my question, is it poorly made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I noticed some of your code is [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript), but I'm going to answer your question about `console.log` and the `res` object in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

The following code assumes that your JSON response is exactly as you posted in your question and as follows:

```json
{
  "status": true,
  "data": {
    "cServico": {
      "Codigo": "04510",
      "Valor": "65,00",
      "PrazoEntrega": "6",
      "ValorSemAdicionais": "65,00",
      "ValorMaoPropria": "0,00",
      "ValorAvisoRecebimento": "0,00",
      "ValorValorDeclarado": "0,00",
      "EntregaDomiciliar": "S",
      "EntregaSabado": "N",
      "obsFim": {},
      "Erro": "0",
      "MsgErro": {},
    },
  },
}
```

In this case, getting the `Valor` property in this would require accessing `res.data.cServico.Valor`. If you're receiving `undefined`, then I have to assume that these properties do not exist in your test (which means I'm not able to reproduce the problem).

This example can be seen in the following snippet:

```js
const res = {
  "status": true,
  "data": {
    "cServico": {
      "Codigo": "04510",
      "Valor": "65,00",
      "PrazoEntrega": "6",
      "ValorSemAdicionais": "65,00",
      "ValorMaoPropria": "0,00",
      "ValorAvisoRecebimento": "0,00",
      "ValorValorDeclarado": "0,00",
      "EntregaDomiciliar": "S",
      "EntregaSabado": "N",
      "obsFim": {},
      "Erro": "0",
      "MsgErro": {},
    },
  },
};
console.log(res.data.cServico.Valor);
```

If you receive `undefined`, I would suggest checking the parent parameters until you get something other than `undefined` to trace the source of your error.

```js
console.log(res.data.cServico);
console.log(res.data);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `undefined` for `console.log(res.value)` because as you can see, your response doesn't have a `value` field.
To get the value of field `Valor` use `console.log(res.data.cServico.Valor)`.
(that's because you have an object `cServico` embedded in the `data` object from your response).

Comment: thanks for the reply but it still returns the error
ERROR TypeError: Unable to read properties of undefined (reading 'cServico')

Comment: Maybe there's actually an undefined at some time. Put console.log(res?.data?.cServico?.Valor);

Comment: And this applies for the next line as well. this.freteCorreio = res?.data?.cServico?.Valor

Comment: returns undefined, but I didn't understand it, and in the json it has the valor: 65

Comment: Just console.log(res) and see what’s the actual response and its shape